# Jenkins Slave Doesn't Use Same Ruby Version As On Local Terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins, rubygems

I am using a OSX Jenkins slave to run some build commands for Xcode. When I run gem environment in my local terminal, this is what I get.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

This is what I expect. Now when I run the exact same command through Jenkins, I get this

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 645) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
     - /Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I'm running everything in the same directory, the same user, nothing is different, so why is the ruby version and directories wrong? The only config setting in my Jenkins Slave is the `PATH` variable which has the value

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/nvitas/.rvm/bin:/Users/nvitas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
```

Other than that everything is what comes installed.

Comment: Can you post more info about your jenkins config and your gemfile

Answer (score 1):

When jenkins executes your script it doesn't access your local ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zhrc which will setup or reference your ruby package manager setup.

Add whatever is in either your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zhrc to the build script in Jenkins project config.

In my case I'm using chruby, the simplest one in my experience - so I add this below #!/bin/zsh -l in jenkins script. Your first line might say #!/bin/bash...

```
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh

source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-2.7.2
```

If you're using rbenv you would likely be including this instead:

```
~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM please use the below script

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Now you can run all rvm commands